# Spotfire: Fill nulls with previous value in calculated column

Tags: null, fill, spotfire

I've made a case statement to basically tell me when different zones are open/partially open/closed for different wells on different dates.  But this only changes periodically, so there are several null values between status changes that I want to carry forward with the previous status's value.  Ideally I'd want to have that in the same calculation as the case statement, but you apparently can't use cyclical arguments there so I'm okay with creating a new column to do this but I'm still having trouble filling the blanks.

A simplified version of my data set is below, with the current outputs in the '1st' and '2a' columns returning a 0 when there's nothing downhole, a 0.5 if it's partially ported, and a 1 if it's blanked. Right now, I just have in the case statement to return a null if there's no change that month for that well.

```
Well  Date    Zone In  Size In  Zone Out  Size Out    1st   2a
101  1/2019                     2a        blank             0
101  2/2019
101  3/2019    2a       blank                               1
101  4/2019    1st      port                          0.5   
101  5/2019                                           
101  6/2019                                           
101  7/2019                      1st      port        0
```

Below is the status I would like for the '1st' and '2a' columns.

```
Well  Date    Zone In  Size In  Zone Out  Size Out    1st   2a
101  1/2019                     2a        blank       0     0
101  2/2019                                           0     0
101  3/2019    2a       blank                         0     1
101  4/2019    1st      port                          0.5   1
101  5/2019                                           0.5   1
101  6/2019                                           0.5   1
101  7/2019                      1st      port        0     1
```

Or

```
Well  Date    Zone In  Size In  Zone Out  Size Out    1st   2a  1st filled  2a filled
101  1/2019                     2a        blank             0   0           0
101  2/2019                                                     0           0
101  3/2019    2a       blank                               1   0           1
101  4/2019    1st      port                          0.5       0.5         1
101  5/2019                                                     0.5         1
101  6/2019                                                     0.5         1
101  7/2019                      1st      port        0         0           1
```

As I said previously, I'm using a case statement for these columns since the input zone/size data I'm given is a bit more complicated than what I'm showing here so having a secondary '1st filled' and '2a filled' columns is acceptable if necessary.

..

If anyone wants/needs it, an example of my current case statement in the simplest zone is below:

```
case    
when ([Zone In]="1st") and ([Port_Size In]=0) then 1   
when ([Zone In]="1st") and ([Port_Size In]!=0) then 0.5   
when [Zone Out]="1st" then 0  
else NULL  
end
```

(In the input data, a value of 0 means it's blanked, anything else is a port size, hence the code not exactly matching the simplified data example.)

Any help that anyone could give me would be very much appreciated!!! Please let me know if you need any other info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out!  I used this for the '1st Filled' column.

```
SN(last([1st]) OVER (Intersect([Well],AllPrevious([Date]))),0)
```

Thank you so much for the inspiration Gaia!

Comment: Unfortunately the example given did not accurately reflect the issue (only one well shown)

Answer (score 0):

Try this for 1st filled, and the same pattern for 2a filled:

SN(LastValidBefore([1st]),0)

LastValidBefore takes the last valid value before the current one.
SN puts a zero where there is no such valid value (at the start).

Gaia

Comment: That worked!  Good Lord, I could have sworn I'd already tried that multiple times but I guess I wasn't doing the syntax right or something.  Whew!  I knew this should have been pretty easy, thank you so much! :)

Comment: Just kidding.  That kind of works.  But it doesn't take into account the intersect of different wells.  When it transitions from one well to another, it just continues the data from the previous well and I'm stuck with the same problem of not being able to use an over or an aggregation method with the SN function